# PHP Convert 09/23/2014 11:42:27 pm into Epoch timestamp

Tags: timestamp, epoch

Newb question but im having incredible trouble getting a clear answer on how to convert a date formatted like this to epoch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easy just use `strtotime('09/23/2014 11:42:27 pm')` but it's time zone dependent

for me Europe/Prague

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Prague');
echo @strtotime('09/23/2014 11:42:27 pm');
```

checked with this tool: http://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html